# cannot implicitly convert type system.data.entity.infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<> . An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have used a SqlQuery function to run an stored procedure. My Stored Procedure returns `IEnumerable<String>`. The return data of `SqlQuery()` is `DbRawSqlQuery<IEnumerable<String>>`. How can I convert it to `IEnumerable<String>`?

Comment: Well, you've currently got a sequence of sequences. Are you trying to flatten it? You haven't shown us any of your code, or told us what the stored proc does... that makes it hard to help you.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to help people help you, that's fine. But right now, you could get more help if you would provide more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you have some code that looks like this:

```
var raw = context.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<string>>(/*SQL*/);
```

What you probably want instead is something like this:

```
var raw = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(/*SQL*/);
```

The type argument to `SqlQuery<TElement>` should be the type of the element in the sequence returned.